# How get value from SQL String? vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have some code that works perfectly but I am not sure how to get value from String?

```
Dim SelectQuery As String = "SELECT OrderID FROM Orders_Header"
        Dim WhereQuery As String = " WHERE 1=1"

    Dim SO As String = BOX_SearchSO.Text
    Dim RowID As Integer = Nothing

    If SO = Nothing Then
        LBL_Status.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        LBL_Status.Text = "Please insert SO !"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If SO <> Nothing Then
        WhereQuery = WhereQuery & " AND DVMOrderNumber LIKE '" & "%" + SO + "%" & "'"
    End If

    Dim myQuery As String = SelectQuery & WhereQuery
```

MyQuery is the complete SQL Query, how do I get value from String?

Comment: Just show final string that you're getting in `myQuery` variable

Comment: A bit offtopic but your query concatinating is high vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: But i need a value of Query...not string

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    con = FunctionConnection()
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = myQuery
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    con.Open()
    RowID = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    con.Close()
```

This is solution